# Use pydrill storage_update() to create Apache drill storage

Tags: python-3.6, apache-drill, pydrill

I am trying to create MySQL apache drill storage plugin using pydrill. It is throwing error:

> RequestError: TransportError(400, 'Unrecognized field "type" (class org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.PluginConfigWrapper), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "config", "name"])\n at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@1843f42f; line: 1, column: 138] (through reference chain: org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.PluginConfigWrapper["type"])')
>   Here is my code:

```
drill = PyDrill(host='host',port='8047',user='xx')

configu = '{"type": "jdbc","driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","url": "jdbc:mysql://host:3306","username": "xx","password": "xx",enabled:true}'
drill.storage_update('MySQL1',configu)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution. We need to pass the storage name as a parameter, and as a json 'key':'value' in the config parameter. 
Here is the corrected code:

```
configu={'config': {'driver': 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','enabled': True,'password': 'xyz','type': 'jdbc','url': 'jdbc:mysql://host:3306','username': 'xx'},'name':'xxx'}

drill.storage_update('xxx',config=configu)
```

And Bingo! It worked!